# C# this keyword - My understanding

Tags: c#, this

The original code and explanation is as following:

The this reference refers to the instance itself. In the following example, the
Marry method uses this to set the partner’s mate field:

```
public class Panda
{
    public Panda Mate;
    public void Marry(Panda partner)
    {
        Mate = partner;
        partner.Mate = this;
    }
}
```

I created the following code:

```
public class Panda
{
    public Panda Mate;
    public void Marry(Panda partner)
    {
        Mate = partner;
        partner.Mate = this;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Panda PA1 = new Panda();
        Panda PA2 = new Panda();
        PA1.Marry(PA2);
    }
}
```

and I drew a diagram based on my code as following:

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxNof.png)

So based on my understanding, PA1's Mate is now pointing at PA2's object in the heap, and PA2's Mate is now pointing at PA1's object in the heap.

Am I understanding this keyword in this situation correctly? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can close this question

Comment: Not really important for your understanding, but your diagram hints to a common misunderstanding. The code of Marry method is not duplicated between the two (or three or n) instances of the class but both instances have an hidden field (called method table) that points to the area of memory where the code of the Marry method lies and is used by any instance of the Panda class.

Comment: Hi @Steve, thank you so much for pointing it out. I am new to C# so I do have a lot of misunderstandings regarding the code itself. If possible, may I kindly ask you to draw a simple diagram for me to illustrate your answer to help me understand?

Comment: Your diagram looks good but just keep the methods of the Panda class outlined in a different way (for example with a - - -  instead of a solid line) to highlight the common nature of the method code. It is just a convention and if you search your diagramming tool you will find some specific way to illustrate the concept

Comment: @Steve thank you so much for kindly pointing it out, I took the notes of what you said and it is very helpful to me

Comment: Perhaps is a bit advanced but http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/03/15/virtual-method-dispatch-and-object-layout-changes-in-clr-40/

Comment: @Steve again thank you so much for helping me, I really appreciate it. I will try to understand what you said correctly! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your under standing is clear. **This** holds the instance of current class object.

Answer (score 0):

See this code you have (I changed the naming so it is easier to read):

```
Panda george = new Panda();
Panda elaine = new Panda();
george.Marry(elaine);
```

When you call the `Marry` method, you are passing `elaine` as argument. But here is the part which is not obvious: Another argument is passed before `elaine` and that argument is `george`. Yes `george` is passed *implicitly* because `Marry` is an instance method and the instance you are calling it on is `george`. This implicitly passed argument is pushed onto the stack of the `Marry` method and it is named `this`. Therefore, inside the method `Marry` which looks like this:

```
public void Marry(Panda partner)
{
    Mate = partner;
    partner.Mate = this;
}
```

The explicit argument you passed is `partner` so it will will be `elaine` but the implicitly passed argument is `george`. Therefore, `this` within the `Marry` method will mean and refer to `george`. Thus this line of code:

```
partner.Mate = this;
```

means *elaine.Mate = george*.

So in conclusion, an implicit argument is always passed to instance methods and the argument is the object on which the instance method is called. That argument becomes the `this` parameter.

Off topic but closely related: this is more ore less how [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) can be treated like instance methods. The first parameter of an extension method is always `this`.